# Map many to many objects using Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

For example we have profile and organisation. Both have articles.

```
    public class Article
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }

    public class Profile
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Article> Articles { get; set; }
    }

    public class Organisation
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Article> Articles { get; set; }
    }
```

In this way Article should have two kinds of parent so it should have something like parent type to be able to access a parent when you select articles directly.

```
    public class Article
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public int ParentId { get; set; }
        public ArticleParentType Parent { get; set; }
    }
```

1. Is it possible to map it using Entity Framework?
2. Is it a good idea to do it?
3. What is the best practice for storing this kind of data?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> public class Article
> {
>     public int Id { get; set; }
>     public string Title { get; set; }
>     public int ParentId { get; set; }
>     public ArticleParentType Parent { get; set; }
> }
> ```
>
> 1. Is it possible to map it using Entity Framework?
> 2. Is it a good idea to do it?

Possible yes but not a good idea. The underlying Database can't use a foreign key for Parentid. It would be slow.

> 3. What is the best practice for storing this kind of data?

A simple approach,  with 2 Nullable parents and without CascadeOnDelete:

```
public class Article
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual Profile Profile { get; set; }
    public virtual Organisation Organisation { get; set; }
}
```

Alternatively you could use inheritance for Article, ie `class OrganisationArticle : Article {}`

Comment: For example I decided to use "A simple approach, with 2 Nullable parents".. but there are many other questions. For example there is a post -> comments structure. Comment has two creators - User and Organisation. Should I add .Include() to each creator when I select posts from DB? What to do if you have 10 parents?

Comment: How exactly to refactor the class model?